# app won't open after downloading

Tags: android, manifest

some of my customers are having trouble opening their apps after downloading them. here is my last 1 star customer review:

'Only playable in play store using open/uninstall buttons. When select on phone app phone says app not installed. uninstalling.'

I'm getting a lot of 1 star ratings because of this and it's killing me. I also get some 5 star ratings so apparently this issue only affects some users. it works fine with my phone, but won't open on a friend's, unless she opens it from the store. I may have upgraded my targetSdkVersion from 16 to 19 recently.

here is my manifest, slightly edited for privacy, I've read of opening issues on another post being caused by bad manifest settings, but none of the suggestions related to my manifest settings:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mypackage"
android:sharedUserId="com.myshareduserid"
android:versionCode="300"
android:versionName="3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"/>
  <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USB" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:debuggable="false" android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
    <activity
        android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
      uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
          <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|
       uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
 </application>
```

Comment: I would advice you to try running it on your friend device and connect it to your pc while running logcat to see if there is any error while you open the app...

Comment: if I see my friend again i'll try to arrange a test with the log as suggested, good idea. my code is not writing to any external files, outside of sharedpreferences, I believe I had to add the external storage permission command from Anroid Analytics instructions to track my app usage. they also had me add a special xml file. some of my apps also have licensing code.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bug in your client's launcher app.
You cannot do a thing about that.

It might be a badly made custom launcher, or a bug, but it's out of your hands.

If that user has access to a custom recovery, he could wipe dalvik and cache, it always worked for me in that case.